# Copy all values in Column D from unknown number of worksheets with unknown number of rows into a single Column A of values in a master worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first question on SO and I'd really appreciate the direct help:

I have an Excel file with multiple worksheets. In Column D of each worksheet, I've created insert SQL statements based on each row's dynamic data. I'd now like to copy all of the insert statements that I've created in Column D on each worksheet into one big column so I can run them all into my database.

Thanks SO much for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To implement:**

1. Create new sheet titled `Master`
2. Give cell `A1` a header name
3. Open VBE
4. Insert Module
5. Copy and paste code **as is** into module

**The code will:**

1. Loop through each sheet
2. Copy cells in `Col D` from `D2 To Last Non-Blank Row`
3. Paste values only on `Master` in next available Non-Blank Row in `Col A`
4. Loop 2 - 3 for all sheets

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub MyDearMacro()

Dim ws As Worksheet, Master As Worksheet
Set Master = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")

Dim CopyRange As Range, PasteRange As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Master" Then
            Set CopyRange = ws.Range("D2:D" & ws.Range("D" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
            Set PasteRange = Master.Range("A" & Master.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            CopyRange.Copy: PasteRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next ws
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Please take the tour page of Stack OverFlow and show an attempt to solve on your next post.", vbCritical

End Sub
```

**Closing Notes:**

You will need to amend this if you do not want duplicates (if they exist). You may also need to amend this if your SQL Statements do not cover every row in the copy range (you may end up with blank cells separating your Statements). AKA once loop is done, remove blanks and duplicates in `Col A` on `Master` sheet.

Comment: I can't thank you enough! I really appreciated the clear directions on how to implement your solution. I also appreciated your MsgBox at the end. :-)

Comment: Just saw this today - how do I clear the question out of the unanswered queue?